# Разная скорость воспроизведения игр на разных ноутбуках в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я сделал игру на своем старом ноутбуке на движке Unity, там скорость движения главного героя и объектов в самом редакторе была нормальной. Сейчас я экспортировал файл с проектом .unitypackage в новый проект на новый ноутбук, и скорость увеличилась раза в 2-3 и иногда она замедляется. Можно ли это как-то исправить или надо подгонять под своё "железо" ноутбука?
P.s. скорость увеличивается и в 2D проектах и в 3D проектах.

Comment: Самое время разобраться зачем придумали поле [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

Comment: самое вероятное, что дело в том, что какие-то вычисления в Update() не используют Time.deltaTime. Из-за этого чем больше кадров в секунду - тем "быстрее" игра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем <strike>навороченнее</strike> быстрее в у вас компьютер, тем больше FPS (frames per second) - кадров в секунду. Метод Update срабатывает каждый кадр.

Логично, что если вы в Update двигаете героя, например, на 1 вправо, то при FPS=50 он за секунду сдвинется на 50 клеток, при FPS=100 - в два раза дальше.

Чтобы это предотвратить есть [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html), который равен `The completion time in seconds since the last frame. This property provides the time between the current and previous frame` - `Время в секундах с момента завершения последнего кадра. Это свойство отвечает за время между текущим и предыдущим кадром`. Сответственно, если вы будете домножать длину вектора перемещения на `Time.deltaTime`, то ваш объект будет за секунду проодить одинаковое расстояние вне зависимости от FPS.

Пример:

```
private float Update () {
    Player.transform.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

С помощью этого свойства можно также реализовать таймер.

```
private float  timer;
private float Update () {
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Через X секунд переменная timer будет равна X вне зависимости от FPS

А вообще, если у вас движение физическое, то следует использовать [FixedUpdate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html), который вызывается 50 раз в секунду (каждый 0.02с) вне зависимости от FPS.

Связано: [Time.fixedDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)